# NPException when calling target in JAX-RS 2.0 CXF in Liberty Profile under WebSocket listener with nv-websocket-client

Tags: websocket, cxf, java.util.concurrent

I am getting this NullPointerException when invoking a simple JAX-RS 2.0 REST client routine. My method (CogniAPIRESTClient.performQuery() ) is working OK in many places in my application, but fails when it is invoked from the Thread created by NV-WebSocketClient WebSocket listener as can be seen in the exception trace:

```
[3/13/16 20:54:47:789 CET] 000000ba id=         com.cogniapi.ElizaDemoView                                   E Exception handling audio content
 java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.client.bus.LibertyJAXRSClientBusFactory.getClientScopeBus(LibertyJAXRSClientBusFactory.java:89)
     at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.client.JAXRSClientImpl.target(JAXRSClientImpl.java:109)
     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl.target(ClientImpl.java:100)
     at com.cogniapi.ws.rs.client.CogniAPIRESTClient.performQuery(CogniAPIRESTClient.java:44)
     at com.cogniapi.ElizaDemoView.onMessage(ElizaDemoView.java:145)
     at com.cogniapi.speechtotext.WebSocketSpeechToTextClient$WebSocketListener.onTextMessage(WebSocketSpeechToTextClient.java:116)
     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnTextMessage(ListenerManager.java:352)
     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnTextMessage(ReadingThread.java:233)
     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnTextMessage(ReadingThread.java:211)
     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleTextFrame(ReadingThread.java:910)
     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:693)
     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:102)
     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.run(ReadingThread.java:61)
```

I have checked the REST parameters and they are correct, in fact it works if I invoke the method with same parameters from the class postConstruct for example

It has to do with that thread not being a Liberty managed thread but even though I am invoking the connect() method with a ManagedExecutor, that managed executor seems not to be used by nv-websocket-client library to create the thread taking care of the callback/listener calls, so when it is invoked I get the exception. Any ideas of how I can make that thread to be container managed?

Note: The library: https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client

Thanks, Ignacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)** internally creates two threads after a WebSocket connection is established. One to receive WebSocket frames from the WebSocket server and the other to send WebSocket frames to the WebSocket server. Most callback methods listed in `WebSocketListener` are called by either of the threads.

If your code has to run in a specific thread (a Liberty managed thread), you should pass the data you receive via `onTextMessage` to the thread. For example, if the thread exposes an instance of `BlockingQueue` by `getQueue()` method, you can pass a message to the thread via the queue like below.

```java
public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) {
    // Pass the message to the Liberty managed thread.
    theThread.getQueue().add(message);
}
```

You can find utility classes under `java.util.concurrent` package to share data among threads.